# How to put date format in php

Tags: php, date, formats

I have some php code that calls a date with $modified[$x] that I need formatted to (D, d M Y H:i:s T) for an RSS feed.

the date looks like `20130306` when it currently displays

the time should be 10am

I have been trying to use `date_format($date, 'D, d M Y H:i:s')`, but I can't get it to work

the array I am trying to format is built with
    $modified[$x]=$year . $month . $day;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime( '20130306 10am' ) );
```

or:

```
$date = new DateTime('20130306 10am');
$date->format('D, d M Y H:i:s T');
```

Example:

```
$modified[$x] = date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime( $year.$month.$day.' 10am' ) );
```

Comment: I guess I'm wonder how to do format the dates inside the array

Comment: If time is 10am then try `$modified[$x]=$year.$month.$day.' 10am'`, and then pass that to date function `date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime( $modified[$x] ) )`, I hope that I understood the question.

Comment: Or maybe something like `$modified[$x]=date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime( $modified[$x].' 10am' ) );`

Comment: This worked perfect $modified[$x]=$year.$month.$day;
    $modified[$x]=date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime( $modified[$x].' 10am' ) );

Answer (score 2):

try

```
date_format('D, d M Y H:i:s',$date)
```

if $date is a string you may need to do

```
date_format('D, d M Y H:i:s',strtotime($date))
```